# Existence of bases for $L^2(X,\mu )$ with special properties.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $\mu $ be a Borel probability measure on $X$.  The following questions regard
the existence of
orthonormal bases  for
the complex  Hilbert space $L^2(X,\mu )$ with special properties.

1. Does $L^2(X,\mu )$ admit a basis $\{f_i\}_i$ formed by continuous functions with $|f_i(x)|=1$, for every $i$ and $x$.
2. Does $L^2(X,\mu )$ admit a basis $\{f_i\}_i$ with $|f_i(x)|=1$, for every $i$ and almost every $x$.
3. Does $L^2(X,\mu )$ admit a basis $\{f_i\}_i$ formed by continuous functions with $\sup_{i, x}|f_i(x)|<\infty $.
4. Does $L^2(X,\mu )$ admit a basis $\{f_i\}_i$ with $\sup_i\|f_i\|_\infty <\infty $.

The inexistence of atoms for $\mu$ might be relevant, so you are welcome to assume this in case it helps.

---

If you need motivation for this question, note that for every compact abelian group $G$, with normalized Haar measure, the answer to (1) is affirmative, with the group characters forming a basis.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Dear @Jose,  please note that the questions are intimately related to each other and, in particular, they are listed in decreasing order of strength.   A positive answer to question (1) implies positive answers to all other questions.  It would certainly not make any sense to write four posts for what is essentially just one question.